# Email send through apex trigger are not showing in case feed at case console

Tags: apex, trigger, case, service-cloud-console, emailmessage

I am sending an email message to the case contact after creating the case. I am sending this Email through apex trigger.
But this email message is not shown in console case feed. I am sending another email message when case comment is added through apex trigger and that Email message is get displayed on case feed.

Could you please explain why this is happening??

```
    Code :

if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert){
  List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
  set<id> CaseSet = new set<id>();
  OrgWideEmailAddress owa = [select id, DisplayName, Address from OrgWideEmailAddress where DisplayName = 'test'];
  EmailTemplate template = [SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName='Initial_Response_Email'];
  list<string> Addresscc = new list<string>{'abc@gmail.com'};
     for(case c : trigger.new){
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        msg.setTemplateID(template.Id);
        msg.setTargetObjectId(c.ContactID);
        msg.setccAddresses(Addresscc);
        msg.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owa.id);
        msg.setWhatId(c.Id);


        CaseSet.add(c.id);
        mails.add(msg);
     }
  Messaging.sendEmail(mails);

 }
```

Comment: Do you receive the email sent by the trigger? If so, can you post the code that is responsible for this action?

Comment: Post your code and make sure you have case thread Id somewhere in the email

Comment: Yes Contact is getting email but it's not shown in case feed in console

Comment: I believe you need to create the EmailMessage record against the Case in order for it to appear against the Case record.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have written trigger on case comment object with the same logic which i have used here. Email is sent when case comment is added and that Email comes under the related list for case object without creating the Email message record.

Comment: @Girbot        Kindly reply to above thread..